# sorting in MERN

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Idea**: I want to sort my products on multiple conditions like sort by createdAt by desc or asce, sort by price, etc.
**Issue**: Both are working fine, but how do i check upon user's request what needs to be sorted, either we need to sort the products by createdAt or price.

Here is the code.

```
    const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
      try {

        const sortQuery = req.query.sort;
        console.log(sortQuery);

        const productMessages = await productMessage
          .find({})
          .sort({
            createdAt: sortQuery,
            price: sortQuery,
          })
          .populate("categoryId")
          .exec();
        // const productMessages = await productMessage.find();
        res.status(201).json(productMessages);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
      }
    };
```

Here if i send query to sort products by price it gives me result with prducts sorted by createdAt not by price.

Input: 1  //Sort products by price
Output:   products sorted by createdAt //but i need with price

Comment: You should query your data only once and then render it to make it sorted by any value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check before execution.

like

```
const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const sortQuery = req.query.sort;
        console.log(sortQuery);
        
        let sortObject = {};
        if (req.query.sortField == "createdAt") {
           sortObject["createdAt"] = sortQuery
        } else if (req.query.sortField == "price") {
           sortObject["price"] = sortQuery
        }

        const productMessages = await productMessage
          .find({})
          .sort(sortObject)
          .populate("categoryId")
          .exec();
        // const productMessages = await productMessage.find();
        res.status(201).json(productMessages);
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
      }
    };
```

you have to pass sortField in the query.